# Sample application for AWS XRAY using Scala application

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, aws-xray

Can someone guide me how I can integrate AWS XRAY with Scala application. Reference example would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Dinesh Kumar.

Answer (score 0):

AWS X-Ray does not support Scala application instrumentation right out of the box. You will have to manually begin and end segments/subsegments in your application to get X-Ray traces.

Another preferred alternative is to Opentelemetry to instrument your application and still send traces to AWS X-Ray. See this link to get started: https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/introduction

I'm not sure if Otel Java already has an instrumentation for your use case, but you can always open a feature request with the community.
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/tree/main/instrumentation